# mksquashfs not excluding file

Tags: regex, squashfs

I am having issues excluding a specific file from a squashfs. I want to be able to exclude all file types ending with *.db but have had no luck.

Whenever I run the mksquashfs command with the arguments to exclude the file, it always includes the file. I have tried many different variants of the command. My test script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

OPT="-regex -e '*.db' "

echo -e "Creating squashfs..."
mksquashfs test test.package ${OPT}
echo "Ran the following command: mksquashfs pf test.package ${OPT}"

echo -e "Uncompressing squashfs..."
mkdir pf_post
unsquashfs -f -d test_post/ test.package 

echo
read -p "press any key to continue..."

rm test.package
rm -r test_post
```

The tree of the test directory is below. Both instances of test.db should be excluded but it does not seem to work.

```
test
├── test
│   └── test.db
├── test.ab
├── test.cd
├── test.db
├── test.ef
├── test.gh
└── test.sh
```

Comment: line 10 is supposed to be "mkdir test_post" and not "pf_post"

Comment: Does anybody know how to make this work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555796/mksquashfs-not-excluding-file

I needed to use wildcards instead with the `...` added in front of my exclusion as shown below. It is very important to include a space between the `...` and the `*.db`, otherwise it will not work. I believe I'd tried this method upon recomendation before, but didn't realize when I tried it that there was a space between those two.

```
mksquashfs test test.package -wildcards -e '... *.db'
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the (unwrapped) commandline in question reads:

```
mksquashfs test test.package -regex -e '*.db'
```

The problem is, you're not using regex, you're using shell wildcard. As per `mksquashfs`'s manpage, `-regex` option allows usage of POSIX regular expressions, and `-wildcards` allows "extended shell wildcards (globbing) to be used in exclude dirs/files". So, just replace `-regex` with `-wildcards` in that command line and it should work.

Comment: Switching it to wildcard partially fixed it. That excluded the first .db file, but the second one a sub-directory deeper was not excluded. Is there a way to tell it to exclude all '.db' files and not just the first in the lowest directory? Below is the code that excluded the first file type.

Comment: `mksquashfs test test.package -wildcards -e '*.db'`

Comment: Okay, try this: `mksquashfs test test.package -regex -e '\.db$'`

Comment: @tardis89 did it work? Have it solved your problem?

Comment: I never received a notification that this was answered again. Changing it to that still results with the '.db' file present in the sub-directory.

Comment: Does anybody have another suggestion for this?

Comment: Does anybody have a solution for this?